# react-native-location not updating with latest location on android - always return the cache location

Tags: android, react-native, location, android-location, location-services

react native package - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-location

location is not updating on android. It always return the cache location. But once we re-install / clear cache the app it will take the latest location. Works fine on ios.

```
const getCurrentLocation = async (callback) => {
  RNLocation.configure({
    distanceFilter: 10,
    desiredAccuracy: {
      ios: 'best',
      android: 'highAccuracy',
    },
    androidProvider: 'auto',
  });
  const location = await RNLocation.getLatestLocation({ timeout: 5000 });
  callback(location);
};
```

...

```
const hasPermission = await RNLocation.checkPermission({
    ios: 'whenInUse',
    android: {
      detail: 'coarse',
      rationale: {
        title: strings.enableLocationMessage,
        message: strings.enableLocationMessage,
        buttonPositive: strings.ok,
        buttonNegative: strings.cancel,
      },
    },
  });
```

Comment: I vote to close this, because I do not see what the question is. It looks like a report of something you found out. Consider asking a question or describing a problem according to [ask]and then creating an answer post to provide your solution. Note that StackOverflow only allows Q/A pairs. So if there is no question for you to ask, do not use the "Ask Question" button.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue happened to me and couldn't solve after many hours. At the end, I decided to go with `react-native-get-location` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-get-location) repository and it works fine as I wish.

Comment: Dear @JeanJimenez and Yunnosh, this is exactly the answer, because I share my same experience with the issue and the solution here comes with new package as I linked with my answer. Here again, solution is simple: Please use react-native-get-location instead of react-native-location. Is that clear enough?